# Exclusão de dados relacionados - Entity Framework e C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, delete

Olá,

Usando a mesma estrutura que já venho apresentando aqui a algum tempo, venho pedir ajuda agora para excluir os dados relacionados.
Segue as entidades..

```
public class Artista
{
    public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAtualizacao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArtistaCategoria> ArtistaCategoria { get; set; }
}

public class Categoria
{
    public Categoria()
    {
    }

    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArtistaCategoria> ArtistaCategoria { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistaCategoria
{
    public int ArtistaCategoriaId { get; set; }
    public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Artista Artista { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
}

public class Endereco
{
    public Endereco()
    {
        Municipio = new Municipio();
    }
    public int EnderecoId { get; set; }
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cep { get; set; }
    public int MunicipioId { get; set; }
    public virtual Municipio Municipio { get; set; }
}

public class Municipio
{
    public Municipio()
    {
    }

    public int MunicipioId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Cep { get; set; }
}
```

Neste caso, como excluir um artista.

Quando vou excluir é mostrado uma mensagem de erro.

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Artista_dbo.Endereco_Endereco_EnderecoId". The conflict
>   occurred in database "showfacil", table "dbo.Artista", column
>   'Endereco_EnderecoId'. The statement has been terminated.

segue o código:

```
public void Remove(Artista artista)
{
    var a = Db.Artistas.First(x => x.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId);

    Db.Artistas.Attach(a);

    RemoverTelefones(a);
    RemoverEndereco(a);
    RemoverCategorias(a);

    Db.Set<Artista>().Remove(a);
    Db.SaveChanges();
}


private void RemoverTelefones(Artista artista)
{
    // Telefones Originais
    var telefonesOriginais = Db.TelefoneArtista.AsNoTracking().Where(at => at.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId).ToList();

    if (artista.ArtistaTelefones != null)
    {
        // Telefones Excluídos
        foreach (var telefoneOriginal in telefonesOriginais)
        {
            var telefoneExcluido = Db.TelefoneArtista.Single(rt => rt.TelefoneArtistaId == telefoneOriginal.TelefoneArtistaId);
            Db.TelefoneArtista.Remove(telefoneExcluido);
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

private void RemoverCategorias(Artista artista)
{
    var categorias = Db.ArtistaCategoria.AsNoTracking().Where(at => at.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId).ToList();

    foreach (var categoria in categorias)
    {
        var catExcluida = Db.ArtistaCategoria.Single(rt => rt.ArtistaCategoriaId == categoria.ArtistaCategoriaId);
        Db.ArtistaCategoria.Remove(catExcluida);
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

private void RemoverEndereco(Artista artista)
{
    var enderecos = Db.Enderecos.AsNoTracking().Where(at => at.EnderecoId == artista.Endereco.EnderecoId).ToList();
    artista.Endereco = null;
    foreach (var endereco in enderecos)
    {
        var endExcluido = Db.Enderecos.Single(rt => rt.EnderecoId == endereco.EnderecoId);
        Db.Enderecos.Remove(endExcluido);
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: O *DELETE CASCADE* está habilitado para as tabelas? Caso não esteja, será necessário remover as tabelas debaixo para só depois remover as de cima.

Comment: O Delete Cascade não está ativado e já tentei excluir o endereço e depois o artista e também o contrário, o artista e depois o endereço, nos dois casos deu o mesmo erro..

Comment: Quando exclui o endereço primeiro, tentei colocar o artista.endereco = null

Answer (score 1):

Alexandre, ao invés de utilizar o "Single", tente utilizar o "Find".
Ficaria assim por exemplo:

```
var endExcluido = Db.Enderecos.Find(endereco.EnderecoId);
```

Ele irá retornar nulo se não puder encontrar um item. A questão é que primeiro ele vai olhar no contexto antes de ir para o banco de dados, o que que pode ser um fator de eficiência importante. Eu tive um problema muito parecido com o seu e era que o objeto não estava no contexto para alteração/exclusão. Efetuando a busca pelo Find meu problema foi resolvido.

Outro ponto é o "SaveChanges". Essa é uma dica.
Execute ele apenas no término de todas as iterações.

O Entity abre uma transaction para você executar todos os "Remove" e por fim efetuar o "Commit" dessas alterações, que seria o nosso "SaveChanges".
Ou seja, mantenha apenas o ultimo, que está dentro do método "Remove":

```
Db.Set<Artista>().Remove(a);
Db.SaveChanges();
```

Os demais podem ser removidos.

Answer (score 0):

Tente altera seu método da seguinte forma.

```
public void Remove(Artista artista)
{
    var artistas = Db.Artistas.First(x => x.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId);


    RemoverTelefones(artistas);
    RemoverEndereco(artistas);
    RemoverCategorias(artistas);

    Db.Artista.Remove(artistas);
    Db.SaveChanges();
}


private void RemoverTelefones(Artista artista)
{
    // Telefones Originais
    var telefonesOriginais = Db.TelefoneArtista.Where(at => at.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId);
    Db.TelefoneArtista.RemoveRange(telefonesOriginais);
    Db.SaveChanges();       
}

private void RemoverCategorias(Artista artista)
{
    var categorias = Db.ArtistaCategoria.Where(at => at.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId);
    Db.ArtistaCategoria.RemoveRange(categorias);
    Db.SaveChanges();
}

private void RemoverEndereco(Artista artista)
{
    var enderecos = Db.Enderecos.AsNoTracking().Where(at => at.EnderecoId == artista.Endereco.EnderecoId).ToList();
    Db.Enderecos.RemoveRange(enderecos);
    Db.SaveChanges();    
}
```

Uma coisa que não entendi aqui é o código `artista.Endereco = null;`, até onde eu sei quando você faz o delete o contexto já remove esses dados então não necessita você fazer `Endereco = null;`, outra coisa é o AsNoTracking. esse método faz com que o Enderecos recuperado não sejá controlado pelo contexto assim quando você está indo para salvar o Endereco de volta ao banco de dados você deve anexá-lo e definir corretamente estado do Endereco para que EF.

[Mas detalhes aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211680/what-difference-does-asnotracking-make) e [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.removerange(v=vs.113).aspx)